# Elementary differentiation problem involving logarithms: What am i missing here?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, summation

Consider the finite sum  $S=$ $\sum_{k=2}^n \log k - \log(k-1)$.

Differentiating $S$ w.r.t $k$, we have $S'= \sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k} - \dfrac{1}{k-1}=-\sum_{k=1}^n \dfrac{1}{k(k-1)}<0$.

But this is somewhat a contradiction, since $\log k -\log(k-1) > 0$ for every $k$, which implies that $S$ is strictly increasing and thus $S'>0$ ?

Answer (score 5):

The expression $$\sum_{k=1}^n\log k - \log(k-1)$$
is independent of $k$. You cannot differentiate with regard to $k$. Your calculation is therefore nonsensical, and its results mean nothing.

---

Ask yourself this: does the question

> If $S$ is the sum of the first $n$ integers, what is the derivative of $S$ with regard to $k$

make any sense?

No, it does not. There is no $k$ on which $S$ would be dependent on, despite the fact that $$S=\sum_{k=1}^nk$$

Comment: Oh i see, it's dependent on $n$, not $k$, thanks !

Comment: @User1 Yes, but $n$ is an integer, so you cannot differentiate wrt to $n$.